# im using python to work out the johansen test for my project but it is not showing result?

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

this is the code i wrote:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm import coint_johansen       
import numpy as np'       
x= pd.DataFrame(data['ln_bit'])       
y= pd.DataFrame(data['ln_nas'])        
df = pd.concat([x,y], axis=1)        
coint_johansen (df, 0, 1)
```

the output is just this:
<statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.JohansenTestResult at 0x267feffdcd0>

any help? its not showing the actual result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coint_johansen` returns an object `JohansenTestResult` you can find more details [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.coint_johansen.html)

ex -

```
import datetime

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm import coint_johansen 


test_result = coint_johansen(y, 0, p)

test_result.max_eig_stat
array([200.21744043, 167.84190294, 1.76746927])

test_result.trace_stat_crit_vals
array([[27.0669, 29.7961, 35.4628],
       [13.4294, 15.4943, 19.9349],
       [2.7055, 3.8415, 6.6349]])

test_result.max_eig_stat
array([200.21744043, 167.84190294, 1.76746927])

test_result.max_eig_stat_crit_vals
array([[18.8928, 21.1314, 25.865],
       [12.2971, 14.2639, 18.52],
       [2.7055, 3.8415, 6.6349]])
```

Comment: how would i interpret these values?

Comment: Just convert it into `list` and use like - `list(test_result.max_eig_stat)`